# how to : change css class of a button in a parent window with javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parent, classname

I am trying to change the class of a button in a parent window from a popup.  I can change the display but the change in class does not seem to take effect.  What is wrong with this code that run in the popup?  The change to innerHTML and display works but not the className.

```
   var messages = window.opener.document.getElementById("messages");
   messages.innerHTML="Now linked to Facebook page at "+  link + ".";

   var firstmessage = window.opener.document.getElementById("firstmessage");
   firstmessage.style.display = 'block';
   firstmessage.style.className += ' notice_msg ';

   var choosefanpagebtn = window.opener.document.getElementById("choosefanpagebtn");
   choosefanpagebtn.style.className = "";
   choosefanpagebtn.style.className = "green_button";
```

Thank you.

Comment: Change `.style.className` to `.className`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the .style after choosefanpagebtn:

```
var choosefanpagebtn = window.opener.document.getElementById("choosefanpagebtn");
choosefanpagebtn.className = "green_button";
```

Should work. Not tested, let me know.
Also, this line was unnecessary:

```
choosefanpagebtn.className = "";
```

Because you're not doing +=.
If somehow you did that, and then

```
choosefanpagebtn.className += "green_button";
```

later, I could see that line being useful.

Comment: And you win!!!  but by how much I wonder.  These answers should listed to the  millisecond.  Thanks.

Comment: Haha, no problem! Yeah I'm not seeing an exact post time on here. Thanks for choosing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

just use document.getElementById().className

```
var messages = window.opener.document.getElementById("messages");
messages.innerHTML="Now linked to Facebook page at "+  link + ".";
var firstmessage = window.opener.document.getElementById("firstmessage");
firstmessage.style.display = 'block';
firstmessage.className += ' notice_msg ';
var choosefanpagebtn = window.opener.document.getElementById("choosefanpagebtn");
choosefanpagebtn.className = "green_button";
```

Comment: it might be nicer if you explain what you've done in this code :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the .style in .style.className ?